# How do I send inputs from multiple functions into one function in c++?

Tags: c++

As part of a school assignment, I need to build a modular calculator with at least four modules (getData, getInteger, processData, displayData) doing add/subtract/multiply/divide/modulus operations on two integers.

I'm getting pretty stumped on putting this thing together, and I think it's largely because I'm struggling to understand how inter-function calls work (e.g. one function sending information to another function).

I've got the getInteger function getting integer input from the user, and I'm using processdata(intA, intB); to send this to the processData(int, int) function; but my getData(int) function also needs to send an integer input to processData - however processData(select) isn't valid because it doesn't have enough arguments. (I don't really understand what this means)

This is probably a bit confusing, so I've got the whole (unfinished/wip/doesn't actually work) program here:

```
//calculator program
//4 modules required: getData, getInteger, processData, displayData
#include <iostream> //To input/output to the display (I think)
#include <conio.h>  //For getch() at end of program
using namespace std;

//prototypes
void getInteger(int, int); 
void getData(int); 
void processData(int, int); 
void displayData(); // haven't added anything yet

int main(){


  //prevents window from immediately closing
  getch();     
  return 0;
}

void getInteger(int, int) {
    int intA, intB;
    cout << "Please enter integer one: " << endl;
        cin >> intA;
    cout << "Please enter integer two: " << endl;
        cin >> intB;
    processData(intA, intB); //sends info to processData function
}

void getData(int) {
    int select;
    cout << "Available Functions" << endl;
    cout << "1. Addition (+)" << endl;
    cout << "2. Subtraction (-)" << endl;
    cout << "3. Multiplication (*)" << endl;
    cout << "4. Division (/)" << endl;
    cout << "5. Modulus (%)" << endl;
    cout << "Please type your selection (1-5): " << endl;
        cin >> select;
        if (select > 5 || select < 1) {
            cout << "Error: Out of Bounds, please re-enter your selection: " << endl;
            cin >> select;
        }
    processData(select); //sends info to processData function
}

void processData() {
    int add, sub, mul, div, mod, select, intA, intB;
    switch(select) {
        case 1:
            select = 1; //addition
            add = (intA + intB);
            displayData(add); //sends info to displayData function
            break;
        case 2:
            select = 2; //subtraction
            sub = (intA - intB);
            displayData(sub);
            break;
        case 3:
            select = 3; //multiplication
            mul = (intA * int B);
            displayData(mul);
            break;
        case 4:
            select = 4; //division
            div = (intA / intB);
            displayData(div);
            break;
        case 5:
            select = 5; //modulus
            mod = (intA % intB);
            displayData(mod);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "There's been an error :(" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void displayData() {

}
```

Am I doing this all backwards? I feel like it'd be a lot easier if I could contain this in fewer functions, but it's mandatory to keep it in (at least) 4.

Comment: You're calling `processData` with 2 arguments, but there are no parameter variables in the function definition. Your definition of `getInteger` has the parameter types, but it's missing the parameter names. But that function probably doesn't need any parameters in the first place.

Comment: The `main()` function needs to call one of the functions to start all the processing.

Comment: I think you need to go reread the chapter on functions in your textbook. It should explain how parameters are used, but you clearly haven't understood it.

Comment: [Functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)

a function must be call with the same amount of parameters that are present in its definition.
Example: getData must be call with one int parameter like:
`int number = 0; getData(number);` or directly: `getData(5);`
if the function is defined as void, it doesn't return a value otherwise it return its type. `int main(){ ...code...; return 0;}`
I believe you should check the examples in the documentation and clarify your design...

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations and definitions are not matching with the arguments that you are passing. i.e. void processData() is in your definition, but you declare it void processData(int, int);

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach for this problem is to collect all the data needed in some way, then call the function to do the work. For your case, you'd have to figure out the `select` value, and then the `intA` and `intB` values [1], then pass all three into `processData`.

The other opption is to chain the calls together, so ask for the `select` value first, then pass the `select` to the function that reads the data, and call the `processData` from there.

So you would end up with something like this:

```
void getInteger(int select)
{
    cout << "Please enter integer one: " << endl;
    cin >> intA;
    cout << "Please enter integer two: " << endl;
    cin >> intB;
    processData(select, intA, intB);
}


void processData(int select, int intA, int intB)
{
    ... code goes here...
}
```

I'm intentionally NOT writing the complete code - the way to learn programming is to DO things for yourself. Copy-n-paste is something you probably already can do.

[1] This is a bit problematic, a function can only return one thing. Since you have two different values to return, that's not going to work. An experienced programmer would either use reference-arguments, or return a structure containing both values, but my guess is that's part of what you are learning in a future lesson, so let's skip that idea.

Comment: pass-by-reference is part of the other assignment I'll be working on after this, so if I can use them in this program as well, it'd actually be useful when I get to the next one.

Comment: But it's useful to learn how to work that SEPARATELY from this lesson, I would say. I'm not going to write that answer for you, but if you feel that you can figure it out from your lesson papers or whatever, go at it. The whole point here is that you need to look at the flow of the variables and pass values from one to the next.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working version of your code...  Take note of the changes and also take notice to the use of pointers in getInteger(int*,int*)

Hope this helps you out!

```
#include <iostream> //To input/output to the display (I think)
#include <conio.h>  //For getch() at end of program
using namespace std;

//prototypes
void getInteger(int*,int*); 
void getData(); 
void processData(int, int, int); 
void displayData(int); // haven't added anything yet

int main(){

  getData();
  return 0;
}

void getInteger(int *ptrA, int* ptrB) {
    *ptrA = 0; //safety
    *ptrB = 0; //safety
    int tempA = 0;
    int tempB = 0;
    cout << "Please enter integer one: " << endl;
        cin >> tempA;
    cout << "Please enter integer two: " << endl;
        cin >> tempB;

    *ptrA = tempA;
    *ptrB = tempB;
}

void getData() {
    int select = 100;
        while(select != 0){
        cout << "Available Functions" << endl;
        cout << "0. Exit program" << endl;
        cout << "1. Addition (+)" << endl;
        cout << "2. Subtraction (-)" << endl;
        cout << "3. Multiplication (*)" << endl;
        cout << "4. Division (/)" << endl;
        cout << "5. Modulus (%)" << endl;
        cout << "Please type your selection (1-5): " << endl;
            cin >> select;
            if (select > 5 && select > 0) {
                cout << "Error: Out of Bounds, please re-enter your selection: " << endl;
                cin >> select;
            }else if(select == 0){
                break;
            }

        int intA, intB; //these are set in the following void
        getInteger(&intA, &intB);

        processData(intA, intB, select); //sends info to processData function
    }
}

void processData(int intA, int intB, int select) {
    int add, sub, mul, div, mod;
    switch(select) {
        case 1:
            select = 1; //addition
            add = (intA + intB);
            displayData(add); //sends info to displayData function
            break;
        case 2:
            select = 2; //subtraction
            sub = (intA - intB);
            displayData(sub);
            break;
        case 3:
            select = 3; //multiplication
            mul = (intA * intB);
            displayData(mul);
            break;
        case 4:
            select = 4; //division
            div = (intA / intB);
            displayData(div);
            break;
        case 5:
            select = 5; //modulus
            mod = (intA % intB);
            displayData(mod);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "There's been an error :(" << endl;
    }
   // return 0; void does not return
}

void displayData(int result){
    cout << "The result is: " << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is true, but it can not hurt to see a working example due to the circumstances.

Comment: I'd say it does - but it's your answer; no need to over complicate or teach bad practice (unnecessarily using pointers in this case)

Comment: Over complication, yes. Bad bractice? I disagree.  Thanks for your feedback.